# Poker odds: Chances of a straight flush, given H4,H5

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem, poker

I'm trying to learn Bayes's formula, and am coming up with some poker problems to learn this.

My problem is as following: given a $H4,H5$ ($4$ of hearts, $5$ of hearts) hand, what are the odds that I'll hit a straight flush?

My reasoning is like this:

$$\Pr(\text{straight flush}|H4H5) = (\Pr(H4H5|\text{straight flush}) \cdot \Pr(\text{straight flush})) / \Pr(H4H5)$$

Now, off [of wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability), I learnt that:

$$P(\text{straight flush}) = 0.00139$$

Given that there are 36 ways to achieve a straight flush, and only 4 ways to have a straight flush with $H4,H5$ (namely $HA-H5, H2-6, H3-7, H4-8$), I calculated that:

$$\Pr(H4H5|\text{straight flush}) = 4/36 = 1/9$$

Now, how do we find $\Pr(H4H5)$? My reasoning was: There's a $2/52$ chance that we get dealt $H4$ or $H5$ as the first card, and then a $1/51$ chance that we get dealt $H4$ or $H5$ as the second card.

However, filling out those numbers says there is a 15% chance that this will happen. That numbers seems way to high to me. Surely, somewhere in my reasoning I'm making a mistake. Who can help?

Comment: In order to make it easier to answer your question (in particularly for non-poker players), please be kind enough to provide the following details: 1. What combination of cards does `H4H5` represent? 2. What combination of cards does `straight_flush` represent? 3. How many cards are there of each type (is it $13$ types, $4$ cards each)?

Comment: @Arthur : I meant: suppose you're dealt H4 and H5 as your initial cards...

Comment: @barakmanos: H4 means 4 of hearts, and 5 of hearts. straight flush is 5 adjacent cards of the same suit (e.g. 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 of hearts, or 10, J, Q, K and A of spades)

Comment: That should be $0.00139\%$, i.e. $0.0000139$.

Comment: @Arthur, the OP presumably means that the Four and Five of Hearts are the first two cards dealt. Hence the verb "hit".

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You still have three cards to draw out of $50$.  How many combinations of three cards result in a straight flush?  How many total draws are there?

Answer (score 0):

What are you asking is what is the probability of drawing two cards, without putting them back. 
Probability of drawing first card is 1/52.
Now, there are 51 cards left. 
Therefore the probability of drawing second card is 1/51.
Therefore PR(A & B) = PR(A)*PR(B).